# ASPxComboBox - How to set selected item?

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I'm using : [ASPxComboBox](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/clsDevExpressWebASPxEditorsASPxComboBoxtopic)

The problem is **how to set selectedValue from code behind**? If my html is like this:

```
<dxe:ASPxComboBox ID="cbxJobType" runat="server" width="200px" MaxLength="50">
    <Items>
        <dxe:ListEditItem Text="Contract" Value="0" />
        <dxe:ListEditItem Text="Full Time" Value="1" />
        <dxe:ListEditItem Text="Part Time" Value="2" />
    </Items>
    <ValidationSettings ErrorDisplayMode="ImageWithTooltip">
        <RequiredField ErrorText="Required Value" IsRequired="True" />
    </ValidationSettings>
</dxe:ASPxComboBox>
```

Comment: Why don't you contact DX directly?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Client-Side Script

Give ClientInstanceName property to comboBoxto access it client side and ID property as cbxJobType to access control server side.

```
 // by text
    comboBox.SetText('Text #2');
    // by value
    comboBox.SetValue('Value #2');
    // by index
    comboBox.SetSelectedIndex(1);
```

Server-Side Code

```
// by text
cbxJobType.Text = "Text #2";
// by value
cbxJobType.Value = "Value #2";
// by index
cbxJobType.SelectedIndex = 1;
```

This code works fine too:

```
cbxJobType.SelectedItem = cbxJobType.Items.FindByValue("Value #2");
```

Comment: The code "cbxJobType.SelectedItem = cbxJobType.Items.FindByValue("Value #2");" does not work from editform templates.

Answer (score 4):

You can either:

- Set the **ASPxComboBox.SelectedIndex** property;
- Select the required Item by its Value via the **ASPxComboBox.Value** property:

Code Behind:

```
cbxJobType.SelectedIndex = 0;
//or
cbxJobType.Value = "0";
```

Comment: Setting Value in data bound aspxcombobox does not work correctly. Even in 2020.

Answer (score 2):

On the client side, I found there is the equivalent of Ruchi's suggestion:

> cbxJobType.SelectedItem = cbxJobType.Items.FindByValue("Value #2");

Which is:

```
cbxJobType.SetSelectedItem(cbxJobType.FindItemByValue("Value #2"));
// or
cbxJobType.SetSelectedItem(cbxJobType.FindItemByText("Text #2"));
```

Go [here](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/clsDevExpressWebScriptsASPxClientComboBoxtopic) to learn more about the ASPxComboBox on the client side (ASPxClientComboBox).

Go [here](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/clsDevExpressWebASPxComboBoxtopic) to learn more about the ASPxComboBox on the server side.

There you can browse through all their members, constructors, events and methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at the following

```
cbxJobType.SelectedIndex = cbxJobType.Items.IndexOf(cbxJobType.Items.FindByValue("Value"));
```

Hope though this is posted late, it may help someone else