# ASPxComboBox set value

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I want to set the value in the database in the page load event. I tried many ways but it did not happen. Could you help.

```
   <dx:ASPxComboBox ID="ASPxComboBox3" IncrementalFilteringMode="None"  runat="server" DropDownStyle="DropDownList" Height="30px" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" TextField="SubKategoriAdi" ValueField="SubKategoriid" Enabled="True" SettingsLoadingPanel-Text="Lütfen bekliyiniz">
              </dx:ASPxComboBox>
                  <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSource3" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:baglan %>' SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [SubKategoriler]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

-

```
SqlConnection bagla = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["baglan"].ConnectionString);
        bagla.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter komut = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from urunler where  id='" + Temizle(Request.QueryString["id"].ToString()) + "'", bagla);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        komut.Fill(dt);  
ASPxComboBox1.Value = dt.Rows[0]["SubKategoriid"];
```

I want to select the value of the database from the database but it only writes the incoming value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you can use the [ASPxComboBox.Value](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsASPxComboBox_Valuetopic) Property to accomplish your task.

Try to use the below code snippet:

```
ASPxComboBox1.Value = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["SubKategoriid"]);
```

Refer these:
[ASPxComboBox , How to set selected item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13633256/aspxcombobox-how-to-set-selected-item)
[ASPxComboBox - How to set selected value on load](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q509558/aspxcombobox-how-to-set-selected-value-on-load)
[Set ASPxComboBox selected value at runtime](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q290778/set-aspxcombobox-selected-value-at-runtime)

If you facing some other problem then provide more details.

Comment: when I use the value it brings the value in the ComboBox. The value is not equal to the text.